# JQ Error: Cannot index array with string "pc"

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON File with - from what I understand - , objects listed:

```
{
  "pc": {
    "1.15.2": {
      "protocol": "pc/1.15.2",
      "version": "pc/1.15.2",
      "language": "pc/1.15.2"
    }
  }
}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
{
  "pc": {
    "1.15.2": {
      "protocol": "pc/1.15.2",
      "version": "pc/1.15.2",
      "language": "pc/1.15.2",
      "biomes": "pc/1.15.2",
      "blocks": "pc/1.15.2",
      "entities": "pc/1.15.2",
      "items": "pc/1.15.2",
      "recipes": "pc/1.15.2"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using JQ to add objects to the 1.15.2 array:

```
cat $DP_PATH/dataPaths.json | jq -s '.pc."1.15.2" += {"biomes": "pc/1.15.2","blocks": "pc/1.15.2","entities": "pc/1.15.2","items": "pc/1.15.2","recipes": "pc/1.15.2"}' > $DP_PATH/tmp.json
```

However, on the above command I get:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:501): Cannot index array with string "pc"
```

I do not understand why it's looking for an ARRAY? aren't arrays indicated with []?
How can I add the objects to the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right, but you don't need the `--slurp` mode/`-s`, which puts the whole JSON within an array. Dropping it should work as expected

You can do a manual verification by doing `jq -s . json` which would show your whole JSON wrapped inside the array `[..]`

```
jq --argjson data \
   '{"biomes": "pc/1.15.2","blocks": "pc/1.15.2","entities": "pc/1.15.2","items": "pc/1.15.2","recipes": "pc/1.15.2"}' \
      '.pc |= with_entries(select(.key=="1.15.2").value += $data)' json
```